# Cannot get spring boot actuator to expose endpoints other than the default ones, advice needed

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

I have a spring boot application that's packaged as a `.war` file and running on a wildfly instance.

I just recently added the `micrometer` and `actuator` dependencies to my pom file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

When I deploy the app to wildfly and it's up and running I can access the default endpoints `/info` and `/health` without any problems on the following urls:

```
  http://localhost:8080/myApp/info  
  http://localhost:8080/myApp/health
```

But no matter what I do I cannot access `/actuator` or any of the other endpoints.
I'm currently using an external config file that maps custom properties to a Config class in my app. That config file also contains spring boot properties like these that are not mapped to the config class:

```
###################################################################
# Spring Boot properties
###################################################################
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=500Mb
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=500Mb
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=DEBUG
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

Those parameters are picked up by spring boot without any problems.
I've also added the following actuator properties to the same file:

```
###################################################################
# Actuator Properties
###################################################################
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoint.status.enabled=true

management.endpoint.prometheus.show-details=always
management.endpoint.metrics.show-details=always
management.endpoint.status.show-details=always
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

These properties make no difference, I can only ever access `/info` and `/health`
What am I missing?

**Edit:** There is currently no security module in this application.

Comment: Try by adding following properties, endpoints.enabled=true
endpoints.sensitive=false

Comment: do you see any endpoints registered if you switch on trace level logging for actuator? logging.level.org.springframework.boot.actuate=trace

Comment: try to remove every actuator property except management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

Comment: and how come you access those endpoints by http://localhost:8080/myApp/info  instead of http://localhost:8080/actuator/info ?

Comment: Pls specify the version of spring-boot/actuator/micrometer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot version below 2.0 then try disabling security by using
management.security.enabled= false in properties file